# fill width and vertically center at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

**EDIT:**  I want a rangeslider and its label on the same row, and vertically centred with respect to each other. also, the rangeslider is a flexible width, so i want it to fill the available space.

How do I vertically center a float?

http://jsfiddle.net/v2jaY/8/

Alternatively, how can I get an inline block to fill width?

http://jsfiddle.net/v2jaY/7/

I've jammed both questions into one because the answers I've found for centring a float involve using inline-block and for filling width involve floating.  I need to combine the two.

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
    <div data-role="rangeslider" id="column2">
        <label for="slider-bedroom-min" id="column1">Bedrooms:</label>
        <input name="slider-bedroom-min" id="slider-bedroom-min" min="1" max="4" value="1" type="range" />
        <label for="slider-bedroom-max">Bedrooms:</label>
        <input name="slider-bedroom-max" id="slider-bedroom-max" min="1" max="4" value="2" type="range" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS with float:

```
#table {
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}
#table > label {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}
.ui-rangeslider {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

CSS with inline:

```
#table > label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}
.ui-rangeslider {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: downvotes & close votes should have an explanatory comment, no?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. make label and slider on same level?

Comment: on the same level, and vertically centred with respect to each other.  also, the rangeslider is a flexible width, so i want it to fill the available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone knows a simple way of doing this in pure CSS, please enlighten me.
I use jQuery to achieve these things:
http://jsfiddle.net/MHQ6A/

```
$(function() {
    var $rangeSliderHeight = $(".ui-rangeslider-sliders").height();
    var $label = $("#column1");
    var moveDown = ($rangeSliderHeight / 2) - ($label.height() / 2);
    console.log(moveDown)
    $label.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: moveDown
    });
})
```